# A vector map for South East Asia

Tags: javascript, svg, kibana, jvectormap

I am trying to come up with a jVectorMap for South East Asian countries. I used following links as reference:

- http://techslides.com/creating-maps-for-jvectormap/
- [china jVectorMap - Kibana](https://github.com/loveshell/kibana/blob/d3eadff4f9548d6e689f097ecb2b505716aff364/src/app/panels/map/lib/map.cn.js)
- [few more jVectorMaps - Kibana](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/src/app/panels/map/lib)

from the 1st link's example of South America, I understand that scaling of co-ordinates is needed. with China as reference, Following is my js code for SEAsia:

```
    $.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'asean',{"insets": [{"width": 900.0, "top": 0, "height": 440.7063107441331, "bbox": [{"y": -12671671.123330014, "x": -20004297.151525836}, {"y": 3930392.025135122, "x": 10026572.394749384}], "left": 0}], "paths": {
"MM": {"path": "M670.1,233.39l-1.46,1.11l-1.68,0.11l-0.26,0.19l-1.1,2.7l-0.95,0.42l-0.14,0.42l1.21,2.27l1.61,1.92l0.94,1.55l-0.82,1.99l-0.77,0.42l-0.13,0.39l0.64,1.35l1.62,1.97l0.26,1.32l-0.04,1.15l0.02,0.13l0.92,2.18l-1.3,2.23l-0.79,1.69l-0.1,-0.77l0.74,-1.87l-0.02,-0.26l-0.8,-1.42l0.2,-2.68l-0.06,-0.2l-0.98,-1.27l-0.8,-2.98l-0.45,-3.22l-1.11,-2.22l-0.45,-0.1l-1.64,1.28l-2.74,1.76l-1.26,-0.2l-1.27,-0.49l0.79,-2.93l0.0,-0.14l-0.52,-2.42l-1.93,-2.97l0.26,-0.8l-0.22,-0.39l-1.37,-0.31l-1.65,-1.98l-0.12,-1.5l0.41,0.19l0.42,-0.26l0.05,-1.7l1.08,-0.54l0.16,-0.34l-0.24,-1.0l0.5,-0.79l0.05,-0.15l0.08,-2.35l1.58,0.49l0.36,-0.15l1.12,-2.19l0.15,-1.34l1.35,-2.18l0.04,-0.17l-0.07,-1.35l2.97,-1.71l1.67,0.45l0.38,-0.33l-0.18,-1.46l0.7,-0.4l0.15,-0.32l-0.13,-0.72l0.94,-0.13l0.74,1.41l0.11,0.12l0.95,0.56l0.07,1.89l-0.09,2.08l-2.28,2.15l-0.09,0.19l-0.3,3.15l0.35,0.32l2.37,-0.39l0.53,2.17l0.2,0.21l1.3,0.42l-0.63,1.9l0.14,0.36l1.86,0.99l1.1,0.49l0.24,0.0l1.45,-0.6l0.04,0.51l-2.01,1.6l-0.56,0.96l-1.34,0.56Z", "name": "Myanmar"},
"SG": {"path": "M103.97,1.331L103.82,1.265L103.65,1.326L103.705,1.423L103.818,1.447L103.909,1.416L103.961,1.392L103.996,1.365L103.97,1.331z","name": "Singapore"}
"TH": {"path": "M677.42,253.68l-1.7,-0.88l-0.14,-0.03l-1.77,0.04l0.3,-1.64l-0.3,-0.35l-2.21,0.01l-0.3,0.28l-0.2,2.76l-2.15,5.9l-0.02,0.13l0.17,1.83l0.28,0.27l1.45,0.07l0.93,2.1l0.44,2.15l0.08,0.15l1.4,1.44l0.16,0.09l1.43,0.27l1.04,1.05l-0.58,0.73l-1.24,0.22l-0.15,-0.99l-0.15,-0.22l-2.04,-1.1l-0.36,0.06l-0.23,0.23l-0.72,-0.71l-0.41,-1.18l-0.06,-0.11l-1.33,-1.42l-1.22,-1.2l-0.5,0.13l-0.15,0.54l-0.14,-0.41l0.26,-1.48l0.73,-2.38l1.2,-2.57l1.37,-2.35l0.02,-0.27l-0.95,-2.26l0.03,-1.19l-0.29,-1.42l-0.06,-0.13l-1.65,-2.0l-0.46,-0.99l0.62,-0.34l0.13,-0.15l0.92,-2.23l-0.02,-0.27l-1.05,-1.74l-1.57,-1.86l-1.04,-1.96l0.76,-0.34l0.16,-0.16l1.07,-2.63l1.58,-0.1l0.16,-0.06l1.43,-1.11l1.24,-0.52l0.84,0.62l0.13,1.43l0.28,0.27l1.34,0.09l-0.54,2.39l0.05,2.39l0.45,0.25l2.48,-1.45l0.6,0.36l0.17,0.04l1.47,-0.07l0.25,-0.15l0.41,-0.73l1.58,0.15l1.76,1.93l0.15,2.44l0.08,0.18l1.94,2.15l-0.1,1.96l-0.66,0.93l-2.25,-0.34l-3.24,0.49l-0.19,0.12l-1.6,2.12l-0.06,0.24l0.48,2.46Z", "name": "Thailand"},
"VN": {"path": "M690.8,230.21l-2.86,1.93l-2.09,2.46l-0.06,0.11l-0.55,1.8l0.04,0.26l4.26,6.1l2.31,1.63l1.46,1.97l1.12,4.62l-0.32,4.3l-1.97,1.57l-2.85,1.62l-2.09,2.14l-2.83,2.13l-0.67,-1.19l0.65,-1.58l-0.09,-0.35l-1.47,-1.14l1.67,-0.79l2.57,-0.18l0.22,-0.47l-0.89,-1.24l3.88,-1.8l0.17,-0.24l0.31,-3.05l-0.01,-0.13l-0.56,-1.63l0.44,-2.48l-0.01,-0.15l-0.63,-1.81l-0.08,-0.12l-1.87,-1.77l-3.64,-5.3l-0.11,-0.1l-2.68,-1.39l0.45,-0.59l1.53,-0.65l0.16,-0.39l-0.97,-2.27l-0.27,-0.18l-2.89,-0.02l-1.04,-2.21l-1.28,-1.83l0.96,-0.46l1.97,0.01l2.43,-0.3l0.13,-0.05l1.95,-1.29l1.04,0.85l0.13,0.06l1.98,0.42l-0.32,1.21l0.09,0.3l1.19,1.07l0.12,0.07l1.88,0.51Z", "name": "Vietnam"},
"MY": {"path": "M717.6,273.52l-1.51,0.7l-2.13,-0.41l-2.88,-0.0l-0.29,0.21l-0.84,2.77l-0.9,0.82l-0.08,0.12l-1.23,3.34l-1.81,0.47l-2.29,-0.68l-0.14,-0.01l-1.2,0.22l-0.14,0.07l-1.36,1.18l-1.47,-0.17l-0.12,0.01l-1.46,0.46l-1.51,-1.25l-0.24,-0.97l1.26,0.59l0.2,0.02l1.93,-0.47l0.22,-0.22l0.47,-1.98l0.9,-0.4l2.97,-0.54l0.17,-0.09l1.8,-1.98l1.02,-1.32l0.9,1.03l0.48,-0.04l0.43,-0.7l1.02,0.07l0.32,-0.27l0.25,-2.72l1.84,-1.67l1.23,-1.89l0.73,-0.01l1.12,1.11l0.1,0.99l0.18,0.24l1.66,0.71l1.85,0.67l-0.09,0.51l-1.45,0.11l-0.26,0.4l0.35,0.97ZM673.78,269.53l0.17,1.14l0.35,0.25l1.65,-0.3l0.18,-0.11l0.68,-0.86l0.31,0.13l1.41,1.45l0.99,1.59l0.13,1.57l-0.26,1.09l0.0,0.15l0.24,0.84l0.18,1.46l0.11,0.2l0.82,0.64l0.92,2.08l-0.03,0.52l-1.4,0.13l-2.29,-1.79l-2.86,-1.92l-0.27,-1.16l-0.07,-0.13l-1.39,-1.61l-0.33,-1.99l-0.05,-0.12l-0.84,-1.27l0.26,-1.72l-0.03,-0.18l-0.45,-0.87l0.13,-0.13l1.71,0.92Z", "name": "Malaysia"},
"ID": {"path": "M756.56,287.86l0.69,4.02l0.15,0.21l2.59,1.5l0.39,-0.07l2.05,-2.61l2.75,-1.45l2.09,-0.0l2.08,0.85l1.85,0.89l2.52,0.46l0.08,15.44l-1.72,-1.6l-0.15,-0.07l-2.54,-0.51l-0.29,0.1l-0.53,0.62l-2.53,0.06l0.78,-1.51l1.48,-0.66l0.17,-0.34l-0.65,-2.74l-1.23,-2.19l-0.14,-0.13l-4.85,-2.13l-2.09,-0.23l-3.7,-2.28l-0.41,0.1l-0.67,1.11l-0.63,0.14l-0.41,-0.67l-0.01,-1.01l-0.14,-0.25l-1.39,-0.89l2.05,-0.69l1.73,0.05l0.29,-0.39l-0.21,-0.66l-0.29,-0.21l-3.5,-0.0l-0.9,-1.36l-0.19,-0.13l-2.14,-0.44l-0.65,-0.76l2.86,-0.51l1.28,-0.79l3.75,0.96l0.32,0.76ZM758.01,300.37l-0.79,1.04l-0.14,-1.07l0.4,-0.81l0.29,-0.47l0.24,0.31l-0.0,1.0ZM747.45,292.9l0.48,1.02l-1.45,-0.69l-2.09,-0.21l-1.45,0.16l-1.28,-0.07l0.35,-0.81l2.86,-0.1l2.58,0.68ZM741.15,285.69l-0.16,-0.25l-0.72,-3.08l0.47,-1.86l0.35,-0.38l0.1,0.73l0.25,0.26l1.28,0.19l0.18,0.78l-0.11,1.8l-0.96,-0.18l-0.35,0.22l-0.38,1.52l0.05,0.24ZM741.19,285.75l0.76,0.97l-0.11,0.05l-0.65,-1.02ZM739.18,293.52l-0.61,0.54l-1.44,-0.38l-0.25,-0.55l1.93,-0.09l0.36,0.48ZM728.4,295.87l-0.27,-0.07l-2.26,0.89l-0.37,-0.41l0.27,-0.8l-0.09,-0.33l-1.68,-1.37l0.17,-2.29l-0.42,-0.3l-1.67,0.76l-0.17,0.29l0.21,2.92l0.09,3.34l-1.22,0.28l-0.78,-0.54l0.65,-2.1l0.01,-0.14l-0.39,-2.42l-0.29,-0.25l-0.86,-0.02l-0.63,-1.4l0.99,-1.61l0.35,-1.97l1.24,-3.73l0.49,-0.96l1.95,-1.7l1.86,0.69l3.16,0.35l2.92,-0.1l0.17,-0.06l2.24,-1.65l0.11,0.14l-1.8,2.22l-1.72,0.44l-2.41,-0.48l-4.21,0.13l-2.19,0.36l-0.25,0.24l-0.36,1.9l0.08,0.27l2.24,2.23l0.4,0.02l1.29,-1.08l3.19,-0.58l-0.19,0.06l-1.04,1.4l-2.13,0.94l-0.12,0.45l2.26,3.06l-0.37,0.69l0.03,0.32l1.51,1.95ZM728.48,295.97l0.59,0.76l-0.02,1.37l-1.0,0.55l-0.64,-0.58l1.09,-1.84l-0.02,-0.26ZM728.64,286.95l0.79,-0.14l-0.07,0.39l-0.72,-0.24ZM732.38,310.1l-1.89,0.49l-0.06,-0.06l0.17,-0.64l1.0,-1.42l2.14,-0.87l0.1,0.2l0.04,0.58l-1.49,1.72ZM728.26,305.71l-0.17,0.63l-3.53,0.67l-3.02,-0.28l-0.0,-0.42l1.66,-0.44l1.47,0.71l0.16,0.03l1.75,-0.21l1.69,-0.69ZM722.98,310.33l-0.74,0.03l-2.52,-1.35l1.42,-0.3l1.19,0.7l0.72,0.63l-0.06,0.28ZM716.24,305.63l0.66,0.49l0.22,0.06l1.35,-0.18l0.31,0.53l-4.18,0.77l-0.8,-0.01l0.51,-0.86l1.2,-0.02l0.24,-0.12l0.49,-0.65ZM715.84,280.21l0.09,0.34l2.25,1.86l-2.25,0.22l-0.24,0.17l-0.84,1.71l-0.03,0.15l0.1,2.11l-2.27,1.62l-0.13,0.24l-0.06,2.46l-0.74,2.92l-0.02,-0.05l-0.39,-0.16l-2.62,1.04l-0.86,-1.33l-0.23,-0.14l-1.71,-0.14l-1.19,-0.76l-0.25,-0.03l-2.78,0.84l-0.79,-1.05l-0.26,-0.12l-1.61,0.13l-1.8,-0.25l-0.36,-3.13l-0.15,-0.23l-1.18,-0.65l-1.13,-2.02l-0.33,-2.1l0.27,-2.19l1.05,-1.17l0.28,1.12l0.1,0.16l1.71,1.41l0.28,0.05l1.55,-0.49l1.54,0.17l0.23,-0.07l1.4,-1.21l1.05,-0.19l2.3,0.68l0.16,0.0l2.04,-0.53l0.21,-0.19l1.26,-3.41l0.91,-0.82l0.09,-0.14l0.8,-2.64l2.63,0.0l1.71,0.33l-1.19,1.89l0.02,0.34l1.74,2.24l-0.37,1.0ZM692.67,302.0l0.26,0.19l4.8,0.25l0.28,-0.16l0.44,-0.83l4.29,1.12l0.85,1.52l0.23,0.15l3.71,0.45l2.37,1.15l-2.06,0.69l-2.77,-1.0l-2.25,0.07l-2.57,-0.18l-2.31,-0.45l-2.94,-0.97l-1.84,-0.25l-0.13,0.01l-0.97,0.29l-4.34,-0.98l-0.38,-0.94l-0.25,-0.19l-1.76,-0.14l1.31,-1.84l2.81,0.14l1.97,0.96l0.95,0.19l0.28,0.74ZM685.63,299.27l-2.36,0.04l-2.07,-2.05l-3.17,-2.02l-1.06,-1.5l-1.88,-2.02l-1.22,-1.85l-1.9,-3.49l-2.2,-2.11l-0.71,-2.08l-0.94,-1.99l-0.1,-0.12l-2.21,-1.54l-1.35,-2.17l-1.86,-1.39l-2.53,-2.68l-0.14,-0.81l1.22,0.08l3.76,0.47l2.16,2.4l1.94,1.7l1.37,1.04l2.35,2.67l0.22,0.1l2.44,0.04l1.99,1.62l1.42,2.06l0.09,0.09l1.67,1.0l-0.88,1.8l0.11,0.39l1.44,0.87l0.13,0.04l0.68,0.05l0.41,1.62l0.87,1.4l0.22,0.14l1.71,0.21l1.06,1.38l-0.61,3.04l-0.09,3.6Z", "name": "Indonesia"},
"PH": {"path": "M737.11,263.82l0.25,1.66l0.14,1.34l-0.54,1.46l-0.64,-1.79l-0.5,-0.1l-1.17,1.28l-0.05,0.32l0.74,1.71l-0.49,0.81l-2.6,-1.28l-0.61,-1.57l0.68,-1.07l-0.07,-0.4l-1.59,-1.19l-0.42,0.06l-0.69,0.91l-1.01,-0.08l-0.21,0.06l-1.58,1.2l-0.17,-0.3l0.87,-1.88l1.48,-0.66l1.18,-0.81l0.71,0.92l0.34,0.1l1.9,-0.69l0.18,-0.18l0.34,-0.94l1.57,-0.06l0.29,-0.32l-0.1,-1.38l1.41,0.83l0.36,2.06ZM734.94,254.42l0.56,2.24l-1.41,-0.49l-0.4,0.3l0.07,0.94l0.51,1.3l-0.54,0.26l-0.08,-1.34l-0.25,-0.28l-0.56,-0.1l-0.23,-0.91l1.03,0.14l0.34,-0.31l-0.03,-0.96l-0.06,-0.18l-1.14,-1.44l1.62,0.04l0.57,0.78ZM724.68,238.33l1.48,0.71l0.33,-0.04l0.44,-0.38l0.05,0.13l-0.37,0.97l0.01,0.23l0.81,1.75l-0.59,1.92l-1.37,0.79l-0.14,0.2l-0.39,2.07l0.01,0.14l0.56,2.04l0.23,0.21l1.33,0.28l0.14,-0.0l1.0,-0.27l2.82,1.28l-0.2,1.16l0.12,0.29l0.66,0.5l-0.13,0.56l-1.54,-0.99l-0.89,-1.29l-0.49,0.0l-0.44,0.65l-1.34,-1.28l-0.26,-0.08l-2.18,0.36l-0.96,-0.44l0.09,-0.72l0.69,-0.57l-0.01,-0.47l-0.75,-0.59l-0.47,0.14l-0.15,0.43l-0.86,-1.02l-0.34,-1.02l-0.07,-1.74l0.49,0.41l0.49,-0.21l0.26,-3.99l0.73,-2.1l1.23,0.0ZM731.12,258.92l-0.82,0.75l-0.83,1.64l-0.52,0.5l-1.17,-1.33l0.36,-0.47l0.62,-0.7l0.07,-0.15l0.24,-1.35l0.73,-0.08l-0.31,1.29l0.16,0.34l0.37,-0.09l1.21,-1.6l-0.12,1.24ZM726.66,255.58l0.85,0.45l0.14,0.03l1.28,-0.0l-0.03,0.62l-1.04,0.96l-1.15,0.55l-0.05,-0.71l0.17,-1.26l-0.01,-0.13l-0.16,-0.51ZM724.92,252.06l-0.45,1.5l-0.7,-0.83l-0.95,-1.43l1.44,0.06l0.67,0.7ZM717.48,261.28l-1.87,1.35l0.21,-0.3l1.81,-1.57l1.5,-1.75l0.97,-1.84l0.23,1.08l-1.56,1.33l-1.29,1.7Z", "name": "Philippines"}
},
"height": 250, "projection": {"type": "mill", "centralMeridian": 0.0},
"width": 320});
```

But, the output map is empty. Where am I going wrong?Is it the bbox values? Any pointers on this will help.

Comment: There's a missing comma after `"Singapore"}`

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo..I made SG as a marker and proceeded..will check on this :)